# Ограничить доступ к расшаре

Tags: windows, администрирование

Вопрос в следующем, есть программа, база у которой лежит просто в сети, кроме этого эта программа требует чтобы база была подключена диском, на всех юзерах, причем с правами на запись выполнение, т.е любой пользователь может зайти на диск подключенный и делать там что хочет, какие варианты могут быть, подскажите пожалуйста по ограничению доступа юзера к ресурсу не в ущерб доступа программы к ресурсу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Расковырять под микроскопом куда именно программа должна писать - и дать доступ всем только туда. Остальное - в read only.
2. Инкрементные бэкапы как можно чаще.
3. Допинать разработчиков программы, чтобы сделали нормальную клиент-серверную версию. Вариант из разряда фантастики, но вполне реализуем.